# CodeBlocks compila (sistema operacional linux mint) mas não mostra na tela

Tags: c, c++, linux, codeblocks, mint

Pessoal instalei o CodeBlocks no Linux Mint e assim ele abre perfeitamente você faz o programa ele compila beleza (Se tiver erros ele mostra), porém, ele não não abre a tela interativa (desculpe por essa tela interativa, pois, não sei o nome dela) já desintalei e instalei de outras formas mas não dá certo, baixei com compilador e vem com o GNU GCC se não me engano é isso mesmo, o que posso fazer para arrumar esse erro?

Comment: Você está a falar do terminal ? Já configurou o terminal que o codeblocks deve usar ?

Comment: Não sou novo no linux, eu usava o windows, aí agora que eu fiz dual boot no meu pc é a minha primeira experiência com o linux arrumei o mint como eu configuro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já instalou o GCC ? se não estiver ou se você não saber se já tem, escreva no terminal o seguinte! sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: Fera fui no terminal e escrevi no terminal sudo apt-get install build-essential, aí o terminal baixou os itens lá porém a ide continua com msm problema sou novo no linux, baixei o visual code, eclipse e atualizei o python e tudo deu certo somente o codeblocks deu esse problema vc acha que é bom desintalar e instalar novamente? Aparece na tela depois do f9 It seems that this project has not been built yet.
Do you want to build it now? Aí aperto yes porém retorna a mesma janela

Answer (score 0):

A tela interativa que você fala é o terminal, e pelo que indica não deve estar configurado no seu CodeBlocks.

Para definir qual o terminal a ser lançado no CodeBlocks deve ir ao menu:

```
Settings > Environment
```

Que lhe mostra o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na opção `Terminal to launch console programs` você configura qual o terminal a ser lançado para correr os seus programas. Apenas os que foram instalados no seu sistema aparecerão nessa *dropdown*. Mas se você está a correr o linux Mint já tem pelo menos o terminal padrão que é o GNOME-terminal. De qualquer forma pode instalar qualquer outro que queira utilizar no CodeBlocks.

Comment: Valeu fera!!! Era isso mesmo! Tava xterm -T$TITLE -e  no Terminal to launch console programs aí arrumei gnome-terminal -t $TITLE -x  e deu certo

Comment: @WesleyDornelasOliveira `xterm` é outro terminal. Tanto resolve fazendo como você fez de trocar para o `gnome-terminal` assim como instalando o próprio `xterm` com `sudo apt-get install xterm`.

Comment: beleza fera vou baixar depois